# User with valid credentials can only Login if field "EmailConfirmed" on AspNetUsers is true (NETCORE 3.1)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Following this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1), on my server side Blazor NetCore 3.1 app, I included the snippet below in the Startup.cs, but regardless, it only accepts the login for the users where in AspNetUsers table the "EmailConfirmed" field is set to true AND only if the UserName is equal to the Email:

```
     services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Default SignIn settings.
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;        // Requires a confirmed email to sign in.
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;  // Requires a confirmed phone number to sign in.

        // Password settings.
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        // Lockout settings.
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // User settings.
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> regardless, it only accepts the login for the users where ...

When you look in the standard template code you also have this statement:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    . ...;
```

replace true with false here (or remove the `options => ...` part altogether).

> AND only if the UserName is equal to the Email

With the template code this is hard to avoid. In the Register page the Email value is copied to the Username field. This is a practical measure, you need to ensure unique usernames.

When you want to change this (I wouldn't recommend it) you'll have to scaffold the Register and Login pages, maybe a few more, and alter the code and validations.

Comment: Changing the options as you mentioned solved the problem. Regarding the second issue this link explain it case someone else needs it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825753/support-login-with-email-or-username-for-same-user-in-asp-net-core